# Joining to MAX record by date and joining to another table

Tags: sql-server, join, max

I have the category and product tables. I want to get in one line the record of a product with max date according to the category. If there is no product at all, I want at least to show the category. The ID of the product will be NULL as ProductDate will be also NULL as soon there are no records.

I tried this script and I don't get anything (I don't have a product of the category passed as @ID). If I change the INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN, I will get all the categories and including all the max products. I should get just one record because I'm filtering by an ID

```
SELECT  c.ID AS CategoryID,
        p.ID AS ProductID,
        p.Date AS ProductDate,
FROM Category c
LEFT JOIN Product p
ON c.ID = p.CategoryID
INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT CategoryID, MAX(Date) AS MaxDate
        FROM Product
        WHERE CategoryID  = @ID
        GROUP BY CategoryID
    ) p2
    ON p.CategoryID = p2.CategoryID
WHERE c.ID = @ID
ORDER BY p.CategoryID, p.Date
```

How can I do to get the one record will match with the category more than the product ('cause I don't have any product of the category)?

e.g.

```
Category
C1 Cat1
C2 Cat2

Product
P1 Cat1 Prod1 2015-01-01 ...
P2 Cat1 Prod2 2015-10-01 ...
P3 Cat1 Prod1 2015-10-14 ...

Result
@ID = C2 (Category.ID)

CategoryID, ProductID, Date
C2, NULL, NULL

Result
@ID = C1

CategoryID, ProductID, Date
C1, P3, 2015-10-14
```

---

**UPDATE**

I found the error because I didn't post completely the issue. I was doing this additionaly

```
 WHERE c.ID = @ID
 AND c.Inactive IS NULL OR (c.Inactive = 0)
 ORDER BY p.CategoryID, p.Date
```

I changed to this to fix the problem

```
 WHERE c.ID = @ID
 AND (c.Inactive IS NULL OR c.Inactive = 0)
 ORDER BY p.CategoryID, p.Date
```

But the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33132822?noredirect=1) of Giorgi Nakeuri, simplify my script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is `outer apply` to help you. It is designed for such type of work:

```
select c.id as categoryid,
       o.id as productid,
       o.date as productdate 
from categories c
outer apply(select top 1 p.id, p.date
            from products p 
            where p.categoryid = c.id 
            order by p.date desc) o
```